# Can't include more than one PHP string in dataset

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, d3.js

I'm trying to create a D3.js chart that requires data from a MySQL database. The chart is made using JavaScript, but I want to replace the values with the database value.

This works if I only try to input one value using PHP, but not if I add any more.

```
var dataset = [
    { name: 'data1', percent: <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "".$row["data1"].""; } ?>},
]; // This works
```

The above works, however, this doesn't:

```
var dataset = [
    { name: 'data1', percent: <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "".$row["data1"].""; } ?>},

    { name: 'data2', percent: <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "".$row["data2"].""; } ?>}

]; // Adding another PHP value stops the entire chart from working (it works if I use a non-PHP second value).
```

I also attempted to just use one single `while` loop for all data, but that didn't work either.

```
<?php $connect = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db");  
 $query = "SELECT data1, data2 FROM database WHERE x = y;
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); ?>
```

I know for sure that the data isn't the issue. I've tried the same thing on Google Charts and it worked without issue.

Comment: Check your console, what error is there when you do more rows?

Comment: You are using a while loop to loop over the result set. It doesn't work like an array that resets on each loop. The second one will run zero times because the result is already at the end. The fetch will just return false.

Comment: It says `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'`, but I can't see how that's possible because it works if I replace the second PHP loop with a regular number.

Comment: Please do an real PHP array (or stdClass) and use json_encode() to create the data for javascript.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Oh, I had tried just a regular `<?php echo ".$row["data2"]."; ?>` for the second one, instead of a loop, but that didn't work.

Comment: Also take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php for json generation.

Comment: `$query = "SELECT data1, data2 FROM database WHERE x = y;` please don't post pseudo code with errors, if that is pseudo.

Comment: and your `WHERE x = y` is unclear as to what you're really looking to query for. `y` here, btw is a string literal and needs to be quoted. `WHERE x = 'y'`. However, we don't know what `x` is supposed to stand for, and `y`.

Comment: `SELECT data1, data2 FROM database WHERE x = y` here replace `database ` with `table_name`

Comment: @Fred-ii- so meta

Comment: that being said: ewwww dynamically generated javascript code. this is a yuuge leap, but the correct way is to use ajax, call a php api that will just echo a json_encoded array of your values, then use that ajax response to build your chart.

Answer (score 2):

```
#create an array for the objects
$datasets=array();

#very unclear if your code fetches one or more rows, 
#it seems one row with dataX fields
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
#So we go over it
foreach($row as $field => $value) {
     #create an object that becomes later {name:'abc',percent:'12'}
     $obj = new stdClass();
     $obj->name = $field;
     $obj->percent=$value;
     #collect it in the array, 
     #it becomes lates [{name:'abc',percent:'12'},{...},{...}]
     $datasets[] = $obj;
}
#parse the data into the javascript part of the html content
?>
var datasets = <?php print json_encode($datasets);?>;
<?php
```

Hopefully, you can work with this.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the real code you are using then the first bit of PHP consumes all of the resultset held in `$result` therefore there is nothing returned in the second bit of PHP

```
var dataset = [
    { name: 'data1', percent: <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "".$row["data1"].""; } ?>},

// $result has already been fully consumed    

    { name: 'data2', percent: <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "".$row["data2"].""; } ?>}

];
```

Comment: This is the real code. Any suggestions as to how I can reuse the $result in that case?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you want the resultant dataset to look

Comment: *"This is the real code."* @AlwaysCooking and I Ieft you [this comment...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792075/cant-include-more-than-one-php-string-in-dataset#comment72699444_42792075) earlier which is failing.